# Explode nested list of dictionaries into Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas dataframe created from a list of dictionaries that looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = [{'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot',
  'text': 'Direction: North\nDestination: New York\nNew Customer: true\n',
  'timestamp': '1650907136.554649',
  'bot_id': 'ABC'},
 {'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot',
  'text': 'Direction: South\nDestination: Miami\nNew Customer: false\n',
  'timestamp': '1650907098.340029',
  'bot_id': 'DEF'},
 {'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot',
  'text': 'Direction: East\nDestination: Los Angeles\nNew Customer: true\n',
  'timestamp': '1650906935.705729',
  'bot_id': 'XYZ'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

df

    type    subtype text                                                timestamp           bot_id
0   message bot     Direction: North\nDestination: New York\nNew C...   1650907136.554649   ABC
1   message bot     Direction: South\nDestination: Miami\nNew Cust...   1650907098.340029   DEF
2   message bot     Direction: East\nDestination: Los Angeles\nNew...   1650906935.705729   XYZ
```

I use the following code to parse the `text` column and create a Pandas dataframe consisting of the following:

```
df[['direction', 'destination', 'new_customer', 'foo']] = df['text'].str.split(pat='\n', expand=True)

    type    subtype text                                                timestamp           bot_id         direction           destination                  new_customer            foo
0   message bot     Direction: North\nDestination: New York\nNew C...   1650907136.554649   ABC            Direction: North    Destination: New York        New Customer: true  
1   message bot     Direction: South\nDestination: Miami\nNew Cust...   1650907098.340029   DEF            Direction: South    Destination: Miami           New Customer: false 
2   message bot     Direction: East\nDestination: Los Angeles\nNew...   1650906935.705729   XYZ            Direction: East     Destination: Los Angeles     New Customer: true
```

I then strip some unnecessary detail from the columns:

```
df['direction'] = df['direction'].str.replace('Direction: ', '')
df['destination'] = df['destination'].str.replace('Destination: ', '')
df['new_customer'] = df['new_customer'].str.replace('New Customer: ', '')
```

This gives:

```
type  subtype   text                                                    timestamp           bot_id       direction     destination       new_customer   foo
0     message   bot Direction: North\nDestination: New York\nNew C...   1650907136.554649   ABC          North         New York          true   
1     message   bot Direction: South\nDestination: Miami\nNew Cust...   1650907098.340029   DEF          South         Miami             false  
2     message   bot Direction: East\nDestination: Los Angeles\nNew...   1650906935.705729   XYZ          East          Los Angeles       true
```

So far, so good.  Now, I have the following (**more complicated**) list of nested dictionaries:

```
raw_data_2 = [{'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot_message',
  'text': "This content can't be displayed.",
  'timestamp': '1650905606.755969',
  'username': 'admin',
  'bot_id': 'BPD4K3SJW',
  'blocks': [{'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'BJNTn',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': 'You have a new message.',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'WPn/l',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Heard By*\nFriend',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '5yp',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Which Direction? *\nNorth',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'fKEpF',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Which Destination*\nNew York',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'qjAH',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*New Customer:*\Yes',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'IBr',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': ' ', 'verbatim': False}}]},
 {'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot_message',
  'text': "This content can't be displayed.",
  'timestamp': '1650899428.077709',
  'username': 'admin',
  'bot_id': 'BPD4K3SJW',
  'blocks': [{'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'Smd',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': 'You have a new message.',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '6YaLt',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Heard By*\nOnline Search',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'w3o',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Which Direction: *\nNorth',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'PTQ',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Which Destination? *\nMiami',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'JCfSP',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*New Customer? *\nNo',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'RJOA',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': ' ', 'verbatim': False}}]}]
```

I put this into a dataframe `df2` as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_2)

    type    subtype     text                                timestamp           username    bot_id  blocks
0   message bot_message This content can't be displayed.    1650905606.755969   admin   BPD4K3SJW   [{'type': 'section', 'block_id': 'BJNTn', 'tex...
1   message bot_message This content can't be displayed.    1650899428.077709   admin   BPD4K3SJW   [{'type': 'section', 'block_id': 'Smd', 'text'...
```

How would I parse the `blocks` column of `df2` to achieve the following dataframe?

```
type     subtype      text                             timestamp          username  bot_id     heard_by   direction   destination   new_customer
message  bot_message  This content can't be displayed  1650905606.755969  admin     BPD4K3SJW  Friend      North      New York      Yes
message  bot_message  This content can't be displayed  1650899428.077709  admin     BPD4K3SJW  Online      North      Miami         No
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The solution provided by @onyambu works perfectly on `raw_data_2`, but not on the following `raw_data_3` (which includes another block):

```
raw_data_3 = [{'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot_message',
  'text': "This content can't be displayed.",
  'timestamp': '1650905606.755969',
  'username': 'admin',
  'bot_id': 'BPD4K3SJW',
  'blocks': [{'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'BJNTn',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': 'You have a new message.',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'WPn/l',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Heard By*\nFriend',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '5yp',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Which Direction? *\nNorth',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'fKEpF',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Which Destination*\nNew York',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'qjAH',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*New Customer:*\Yes',
     'verbatim': False}},
             
   {'type': 'actions',
    'block_id': 'yt4',
    'elements': [{'type': 'button',
    'action_id': '+bc',
    'text': {'type': 'plain_text', 'text': 'View results', 'emoji': True},
    'url': 'www.example.com'}]},
             
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'IBr',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': ' ', 'verbatim': False}}]},
 {'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot_message',
  'text': "This content can't be displayed.",
  'timestamp': '1650899428.077709',
  'username': 'admin',
  'bot_id': 'BPD4K3SJW',
  'blocks': [{'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'Smd',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': 'You have a new message.',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '6YaLt',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Heard By*\nOnline Search',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'w3o',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Which Direction: *\nNorth',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'PTQ',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Which Destination? *\nMiami',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'JCfSP',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*New Customer? *\nNo',
     'verbatim': False}},

    {'type': 'actions',
    'block_id': 'yt4',
    'elements': [{'type': 'button',
      'action_id': '+bc',
      'text': {'type': 'plain_text', 'text': 'View results', 'emoji': True},
      'url': 'www.example.com'}]},
             
             
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'RJOA',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': ' ', 'verbatim': False}}]}]
```

It's throwing a key error:

```
KeyError: 'text'
```

Comment: `heard_by`, `direction` etc. are not keys in the dictionary. Where are they and how do you plan to parse it?

Comment: @enke -- the test data has been edited.  There is a "Heard By" key and a "Which Direction" key.

Comment: This looks like something you got from a JSON tree of some sort, I'd suggest looking into [pd.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize)

Comment: It's actually from the Slack API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import re

```
d_new = (pd.DataFrame([[re.sub(".*[*]\\W+", "", val['text']['text']) 
               for val in dat['blocks']] for dat in raw_data_2]).
          drop([0, 5], axis = 1))

d_new.columns = ['heard_by', 'direction','destination', 'new_customer']

d_new
 
        heard_by direction destination new_customer
0         Friend     North    New York          Yes
1  Online Search     North       Miami           No
```

You can then append this to your original data

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu --  thank you for this answer.  This works great on the toy data set.  However, when we add a block to the JSON (see EDIT above for `raw_data_3`), this solution does not work.  Can you help me understand why the error message is complaining about a Key Error for `text`?  Thanks!

Comment: @zeroes_ones This solution is given for the data that was provided.  Note that every data will have a different solution unless a generakized dataset is provided with the logic of what is to be captured. Note that this solution is sufficient to the originally asked question. Consider upvoting(even accepting)the answer. As it solves the original question asked.